No username/password combo appears to work
I'm attempting to install this on a Lenovo Chromebook Duet. I reach the GUI login screen (which does not ask for a username, and does not allow me to select one).
It asks for a password, but none of the following work:
<blank>
phablet
ubuntu
linux
root
toor
my long pin
my chromebook master account password
my short pin
ubuntu-touch
or even @#$!

I've noticed several other people have asked about this, and it sort of looks like they were disregarded - either told to use the above (which doesn't work), or told to read the readme https://github.com/chromebook-unity/create-usb/blob/main/README.md
None of those appear to work.
Exiting to the command line from the GUI, using ctrl-alt-f2 gives you a command-line login prompt that asks for a username and password, and which I cannot see how to escape from. Entering combinations of the above accounts with or without password also gives no love.
I even tried flashing a fresh copy of the image on new media, in case I had a faulty image. No luck.
I've tried getting into safe mode, but the boot loader on these devices doesn't appear to support it. I've tried holding down f2 during boot, hitting ESC, no dice. The only interfaces available appear to be ones where you must log in, and it will not allow login.

Are there any passwords at all that could possibly exist that are not on a very short list?

Are you using Ubuntu with mrchromebox.tech? If so, which version of Ubuntu? Are you using ChromeOS? Are you using Ubuntu touch?

"NOTE: The username is linux and the password is ubuntuunity"
https://github.com/chromebook-unity/create-usb/blob/main/README.md
Also, no success.

I would like to think that the image I downloaded from that page with those instructions would be the image that would go with those instructions, and the information in it would be correct, but I'm not getting success. I've seen a few other posts asking about this password thing, and it kind of looks like people went "can't you read?" and didn't really offer useful advice, but things were marked as resolved. I feel like nobody really followed up or even believed the previous posters.
This works fine:
https://github.com/hexdump0815/linux-mainline-on-arm-chromebooks
So I'll use that instead.

This is not an official Ubuntu project. Only the project maintainers can provide support about it

This question is similar to: How to install Ubuntu on an ARM Chromebook?. This shows how to install regular Ubuntu.

According to the README you shared, the username is linux and the password is changeme.
After you login, you can change the passwd with the command sudo passwd


using ctrl-alt-f2 gives you a command-line login prompt that asks for a username and password, and which I cannot see how to escape from

Try ctrl-alt-f1 upto f7. One of them should work (the one which works changes from Ubuntu version to version. I don't remember which one works currently, but most likely it is ctrl-alt-f7).
